# roscore in docker container not working when called via bash script

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ros

I have created file myScript.sh in which there is only a call to roscore:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo youpi
roscore
```

When this executable script is run from within a container I have no problem with it, both `echo youpi` and `roscore` are executed correctly.

Now when myScript.sh is called from the host (to be executed on the container), I get the `echo youpi` line is executed correctly, but I get not the roscore line that outputs:

```
myScript.sh: line 3: roscore: command not found
```

The command line I use on the host is:

```
docker exec -ti lescompanions /bin/bash -c "source /home/dev/DevRoot/src/catkin_ws/src/le_painters_companion/lc_control/start_roscore_docker.sh && exec /bin/bash -li"
```

Any idea of what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If `roscore` is not an executable in the `$PATH`, you should call it with the path. E.g. `./roscore` or `/path/to/roscore`. It might be that the file permissions are not right, then you need to execute

```
chmod 755 roscore
```